# what is the maximum value I can set for "MAX_OPEN_FILES" configuration in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration

The current Elasticsearch configuration, at my 64GB RAM and 8 cores linux machine has,

At `/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch`

```
MAX_OPEN_FILES=65535
```

when i do ulimit,

```
[root@machine ~]# ulimit -n
1024
```

What is the maximum number I can set for this configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can run `ulimit -n` as the user running elasticsearch to know what's the current limit

You can update the max open files  on your linux server , in `/etc/security/limits.conf`

If your user is called `elasticsearch`, you could add something like this in the file:

```
elasticsearch - nofile 65535
```

or run `ulimit -n 65535` before starting elasticsearch

Comment: My question was : This is my current configuration : 65535. how much more I can increase this value?

Comment: I have updated my question with ulimit and elasticsearch configurations.

Comment: As ```ulimit -n``` returns 1024 you should reduce it to 1024. If you want to increase it, you need to adapt the ```/etc/security/limits.conf``` file or run ```ulimit -n 65535``` before starting elasticsearch. The hard limit in linux for the number of opened files is 1024*1024

Comment: Thats great to know! Instead of increasing open files to 65535, Can we increase it to 100000? how do we know the maximum size to set in linux?

Comment: You should increase it if elasticsearch starts complaining that it cannot open files. The maximum in Linux is 1024*1024 opened files